# Custom Include/ThenInclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to get same result as original `Include/ThenInclude` of EF Core? To make C# use appropriate `ThenInclude` overload for any collection type.

Here is a test code (note I use default EF Core `Inlcude/ThenInclude` in purpose to make a kind of mediator which will be used for other goals later):

```
public interface IIncludableQueryable<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
}

public sealed class Includer<T> : IIncludableQueryable<T> where T : class
{
    public IQueryable<T> Entities { get; private set; } = null;

    public Includer(IQueryable<T> entities)
    {
        Entities = entities;
    }
}

public interface IThenIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> : IIncludableQueryable<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
}

public sealed class ThenIncluder<T, K> : IThenIncludableQueryable<T, K> where T : class
{
    public IIncludableQueryable<T, K> Entities { get; private set; } = null;

    public ThenIncluder(IIncludableQueryable<T, K> entities)
    {
        Entities = entities;
    }
}

public static class ThenIncludeExtensions
{
    public static IThenIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> Include<TEntity, TProperty>(this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity> source, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) where TEntity : class
    {
        var query = source as Includer<TEntity> ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(source));

        return new ThenIncluder<TEntity, TProperty>(query.Entities.Include(navigationPropertyPath));
    }

    public static IThenIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(this IThenIncludableQueryable<TEntity, IEnumerable<TPreviousProperty>> source, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) where TEntity : class
    {
        var query = source as ThenIncluder<TEntity, IEnumerable<TPreviousProperty>> ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(source));

        return new ThenIncluder<TEntity, TProperty>(query.Entities.ThenInclude(navigationPropertyPath));
    }

    public static IThenIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(this IThenIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> source, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) where TEntity : class
    {
        var query = source as ThenIncluder<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(source));

        return new ThenIncluder<TEntity, TProperty>(query.Entities.ThenInclude(navigationPropertyPath));
    }
}

internal class ttt
{
    private void dd()
    {
        IQueryable<A> oo = null;
        IIncludableQueryable<A> sd = new Includer<A>(oo);
        var so = sd.Include(o => o.BsArr);

        sd.Include(i => i.Bs).ThenInclude(o => o.Cs);    // Does not work, vs uses 'ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(this IThenIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> source, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)' and says that 'o' does not have 'Cs' property (since its a List<B>)
        sd.Include(i => i.BsArr).ThenInclude(o => o.A);  // Does not work, vs uses 'ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(this IThenIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> source, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)' and says that 'o' does not have 'A' property (since its a B[])
        sd.Include(i => i.C).ThenInclude(c => c.Bs).ThenInclude(o => o.A); // Does not work, vs uses 'ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(this IThenIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> source, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)' and says that 'o' does not have 'A' property (since its a List<B>)
        sd.Include(i => i.CIE).ThenInclude(o => o.A).ThenInclude(o => o.Bs).Include(i => i.C).ThenInclude(i => i.Bs);           // This works fine because CIE type is IEnumerable
    }
}

public class A
{
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public C C { get; set; }
    public B[] BsArr { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<C> CIE { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public A A { get; set; }
    public List<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public A A { get; set; }
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

However original `Include/ThenInclude` works fine, vs automatically converts List, Array and other collection types to `IEnumerable` and uses

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(
     this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, 
     IEnumerable<TPreviousProperty>> source,
     Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)
  where TEntity : class
```

How to make custom `Include/ThenInclude` behave as the original ones?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Is your question how to turn it into valid code? Also, it would help to know a bit more about these "other goals". So far, I don't see how this adds anything to the standard EF methods.

Comment: @GertArnold yep, the code will not run and need to turn to valid. Create class with relationships (like A, B, C) and use default EF Include/ThenInclude, not imagine there is a lib that must not have anything from EF, this lib uses Unit of work and Repository pattern to get access to DB, how to implement Include/ThenInclude like in EF Core in these patterns in this lib? "Other goals" is just get functions or any other way to use Include/ThenInclude without breaking "Clean architecture" concept - no dependence on external libs.

Comment: Speaking about "clean" architecture... I think `Include` should be an EF concept that doesn't bleed into other layers. What's more, AFAIK you shouldn't even use entity classes outside the data access layer. Which means that there will always be some projection going on from entities to DTOs, domain objects, view models or whatever they're named, and projection means that EF's `Include` is ignored. In other words. I don't see how some `Include` in domain terms could meaningfully be translated into an EF `Include`. They're mutually exclusive.

Comment: @GertArnold first, in you opinion does clean arch supposes using db in application layer? Second i use pattern so the application layer uses the interface without know who and how implements it (EF core or other ones) so by using interfaces i will do dependency inversion. third domain does not use db requests, application layer uses logic to make requests to some storage without knowing what is that exactly.

Comment: if you see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) by dependency inversion achieved with unit of work and repository pattern, they use including properties but names of those props as string, its not good because one of the main bug validator 'compiler' cannot check it at building moment, so to be sure you always need to test this part of code everywhere. 
PS. i know that in link they did not use clean arch, its just an example of DI

Comment: *does clean arch supposes using db in application layer?* -- No, that's why I said "an EF concept that doesn't bleed into other layers." EF is the data layer, the application layer doesn't know how it's implemented. To me it's still very vague what you want with these `Include` methods but I'm pretty sure it's impossible.

Comment: @GertArnold then how application layer stores data, gets data from storage? Again the application layer in my app DOES NOT KNOW anything about implementation of INTERFACES OF UNIT OF WORK AND REPOSITORY PATTERS, it has only interfaces, the implementation is in infrastructure layer. Okay even if its not right for clean arch, just to knowledge how to do this (Include/ThenInclude) by my own?